# Where are Windows Update hashes posted?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1

I have been trying to find some kind of hash posted to verify that the updates downloaded are the correct ones.

I have checked the KB articles posted below as examples:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3020369
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3125574

I also checked the download catalog that requires ActiveX, and neither place has hashes. Is there some place else that Microsoft has posted these, or do I have to generate my own and hope they are the correct files? Thanks!

Comment: you can check the digital signatures. This verifies the authenticity but not the identity of updates

Comment: @Appleblomb Windows 7 or 8.1?

Comment: @rany Both, If I remember correctly all the articles I looked at for 8.1 also didn't have them posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the files via Microsoft download catalog, the files have the SHA1 Hash in the filename, so that you can compare this value to the actual SHA1 hash. Here are the values of the x64 Version of the update KB3020369 that I downloaded via the Microsoft download catalog page:

[image]

Comment: That's not really secure and only ensures you've got the full file without errors.

Comment: @Mario: It's somewhat secure considering that the filenames (and thus, the hashes) came from Microsoft's own site. That said, note how the screenshot also has a "Digital Signatures" tab, which _is_ far more secure than that.

Comment: @Mario How is it not secure?  The files are also digitally signed.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, downloading all the files over again might be a bit tedious but it will work.

Comment: @Ramhound Not talking about the signature. Just the hash in the file name alone.